# Combine Publisher for [Int] Array

Tags: combine

I am trying to create a Combine publisher for [Int], which should fire each time an item is added to the array.

I got the following code but I am unsure what do to inside the filter closure.

```
import Combine

var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

let numbersSubject = CurrentValueSubject<[Int], Never>(numbers)

let publisher = numbersSubject.filter { numbers in
    ???
}
    

numbers.append(12)
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the updated code but in this case, when a new number is added  then I have to call the numbersSubject.send with the new numbers array which triggers the flatMap and all the elements gets printed. I only want the new element to be printed and not all. All elements, should be printed once when then app starts.

```
let numbersSubject = CurrentValueSubject<[Int], Never>(numbers)

let publisher = numbersSubject.flatMap { numbers in
    Publishers.Sequence(sequence: numbers)
}.filter { number in
    number % 2 == 0
}.sink { value in
    print(value)
}

numbers.append(12)
numbersSubject.send(numbers)
```

Comment: There is no such publisher for `[Int]`. You can write code that behaves this way but you need to remove the restriction that it is a "publisher for `[Int]`".